# The value of pixel doesn't change when using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to opencv, I am trying to change the value of all pixels of image by using opencv in python. However, when I show image by cv2.imshow, the image is not change at all although the value of all pixels have been change. Can anyone help me for this situation. Here is my code. I use opencv-python package and Pycharm IDE. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("D:\Image\Others\IMG_0018.JPG", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
i = 0
j = 0
h, w = img.shape

while i < h:
    while j < w:
        img[i, j] = 150
        print(img[i, j])
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
cv2.imwrite("1.jpg", img)
cv2.imshow("Test", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You need to reset `j` between the two `while` statements, or use two `for` loops instead.

Comment: It works! I forgot to reset j in loops. Another question, do you know any method to access all this pixel with high performance. Actually, I want to downsampling all images from my dataset. Thanks very much!

Comment: What do you mean by downsampling? If you mean resizing the image, opencv can do this for you [`cv2.resize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#cv2.resize)